# Create a template that shuffles a dynamic array of objects

Tags: c++

So I need to create a template function that shuffles a dynamic array of dynamic objects. The exercise is guiding me a bit by giving me a starting point.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

template < class X > void shuffle(X ** myArray, int myArraySize) {
  // TODO: Implement here the shuffle algorithm 
}
```

I'm kinda lost on how I should use the pointer inside the function but have a general idea on how the code should be. I know it has a lot of mistakes but it's just an idea.

```
for (int i = myArraySize - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  int index = //a random index in the span [0,i]
  int a = myArray[index];

  myArray[index] = myArray[i];
  myArray[i] = a;
}
```

Comment: use iterators instead of pointers. Even if eventually you will use pointers as iterators it makes it much easier to reason about the algorithm and to implement it. I personally get already too nervous by the mere presence of `**`

Comment: It looks to me like you already have a shuffling algorithm. What is not working? It's not clear what you're asking. Is your question on the `**`? Is your question on getting a random range? Is your question on where you should use `X` in your function instead of `int`? etc,etc. A good question on SO is clear and direct.

Comment: My questions are mainly on where i should use the X and maybe an idea for the random range.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is already a example on how to shuffle a array in the c++ reference at
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/shuffle/
which describe how std::random_shuffle and std::shuffle are implemented

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

template< class T >
void shuffle(T* myArray, int myArraySize){
    int index;
    T temp;
    for (int i = myArraySize - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        index = rand() % myArraySize;

        temp = myArray[index];
        myArray[index] = myArray[i];
        myArray[i] = temp;
    }
}

int main(){
    int* ints = new int[10];

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        ints[i] = i+1;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        cout << ints[i] << "-";
    }
    cout << " Before Shuffle" << endl;


    shuffle<int>(ints, 10);


    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        cout << ints[i] << "-";
    }
    cout << " After Shuffle" << endl;
}
```

Comment: `temp` should be a `T`